# Automating the Importing of Bank Transactions

Tags: acumatica

We are wondering if there is a way to automate the importing of bank transactions in Acumatica.

I see this [here](https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1399) but not sure if there are work arounds or other methods for handling the need.

We just have one bank file we need to upload each day. Can we do this somehow through automated import scenarios? or any other way?

Comment: You should be able to set up synchronization of the file and schedule import scenario. Acumatica will periodically synchronize the bank file which will be used by import scenario.

Comment: Hi Samvel, can you please guide us on how to create and schedule import scenario for Bank Transactions screen. We upload .qbo file manually to the screen. Thank you.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov - i have reached out to Acumatica to inquire the same, but do you happen to know if you are actually able to setup an import scenario for a .qbo file on when trying to import bank transactions? We tried and are not able to figure it out.

Comment: @Cory and John you need to implement .qbo data provider. After that you can create import/export scenarios using that data provider. Please see this blog post regarding that https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/custom-integration-services-data.html